# Multiple multicolumns in tabular messes with text alignment of each other

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, multicolumn

I'm having an issue with multicolumns in a tabularx environment. When I have one multicolumn (in the first row) it is formatted correctly:
[image]

When I add a second row however, the format messes up:
[image]

A third row makes it even worse:
[image]

Here is my TEX:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
 \caption{\itshape raw data table of time elapsed from when the heater is placed within the metal (seconds / at increments of 60 seconds) against amperage and voltage measured at that increment (amperes / volts respectively)}
 \bigskip
 \centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | c | *{8}{Y |}}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Time elapsed / \SI[separate-uncertainty = true]{1(1)}{\second}} &
  \multicolumn{8}{Y |}{Amperage measured | Voltage measured at that time interval / \SI[separate-uncertainty = true]{1.00(1)}{\ampere} | \SI[separate-uncertainty = true]{1.00(1)}{\volt} (respectively)} 
  \\
  \cline{2-9}
  &
  \multicolumn{2}{ Y |}{Trial 1} &
  \multicolumn{2}{ Y |}{Trial 2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{ Y |}{Trial 3} &
  \multicolumn{2}{ Y |}{Trial 4} \\
  \hline
  0 &
  3.62 &
  8.94 &
  3.68 &
  9.00 &
  3.68 &
  9.01 &
  3.73 &
  9.13 \\
  \hline

 \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anyway that I can properly centre the text in each box. Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Make a complete example. It is not known how you defined the Y column type.

Answer (score 1):

An easing working solution would be to simply put a part of the text of the long `\multicolumn` cell in a new row. I assume you defined the Y column type as a centered X type.

```
\usepackage{array}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|*8{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}X|}}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Time elapsed / \SI[separate-uncertainty = true]{1(1)}{\second}} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Amperage measured | Voltage measured at that time interval /}  \\  
& \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\SI[separate-uncertainty = true]{1.00(1)}{\ampere} | \SI[separate-uncertainty = true]{1.00(1)}{\volt} (respectively)}\\ \cline{2-9}
              & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Trial 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Trial 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Trial 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Trial 4} \\ \hline
0 & 3.62 & 8.94 & 3.68 & 9.00 & 3.68 & 9.01 & 3.73 & 9.13 \\ \hline
```

This should work, but surely there is a more elegant solution.

[image]